# Any way to add textures into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2

I am printing my QGIS Print Composer maps in black and white, and I want to make sure that all the different attributes are distinguishable. But I can't select 5 colors that all look distinct from each other in black and white. Is there any way to add like a striped texture or a dotted texture into the QGIS print composer?

Comment: look at colorbrewer.org for b/w printer friendly colors